# Which character is used as an escape character in Liquid Templating language?

Tags: shopify, liquid

This is the code snippet I tried:

```
{% assign page-title = 'Product\'s Description' %}
```

Only **Product\** was stored in the variable. I know I can go with the below given code snippet:

```
{% assign page-title = "Product's Description" %}
```

But just out of curiosity, I wanna know whether liquid language has a escape character or not.

Also, I found something interesting when I tried this code:

```
{% assign page-title = "Product\'s Description" %}
```

**Product'S Description** was stored in the variable. Not sure as to why **s** in the **Product's** transformed to uppercase.

Found this link but it didn't help:
[Escaping Characters in Liquid String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32983352/escaping-characters-in-liquid-string)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since there's no real escape character in Liquid, I had to use this trick for a string that should contain both single quotes and double quotes: `assign str = 'a QtestQ "string"' | replace: 'Q', "'"` which gave the output `a 'test' "string"` (Note: If your string has a conflicting `Q`, use `QUOTE`, `\1` or something else instead.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used this:

```
{% assign page-title = "Product\'s Description" | replace: '\','' | escape %}
```

and the result was: Product's Description

Also liquid have `capitalize` :

```
{% assign page-title = "Product's Description" | capitalize  %}
```